# How to stop iTunes from syncing voice memos from my iPhone?

Tags: iphone, itunes, data-synchronization

iTunes 12.8.0, iPhone with iOS 12.1.2. Sync over wi-fi enabled to sync photos, everything else is manual. Every time iPhone syncs over wi-fi it imports voice memos in my iTunes library and I delete them every time. I don't want them on the computer. Just in the cloud and the phone, that's it. Is it a bug or I need to configure something differently?

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you have voice memos sync enabled:

- Connect your phone via USB.
- Go to phone > Music tab.
- Uncheck 'Sync voice memos'.

[image]

Comment: It shouldn't sync them if SYNC MUSIC is unchecked, isn't that right?

Comment: On catalina that checkbox is gone.